# Taking too long to insert records in Elasticsearch in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, elasticsearch, nest

The following code pulls data from two tables table1 and table2, performs a JOIN on them, over field 3 and indexes it into Elasticsearch. The total number or rows which need indexing are around 500 million. The code inserts 5 million records in one hour, so this way it will take 100 hours to complete. Is there any way I can make it faster?

```
        public static void selection()
        {
            Uri node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
            ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
            ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            int batchsize = 100;
            string query = "select table1.field1, table2.field2 from table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.field3=table2.field3";

            try
            {
                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, con);
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                List<Record> l = new List<Record>(batchsize);
                string[] str = new string[2];
                int currentRow = 0;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                        str[i] = reader[i].ToString();
                    l.Add(new Record(str[0], str[1]));

                    if (++currentRow == batchsize)
                    {
                        Commit(l, client);
                        l.Clear();
                        currentRow = 0;
                    }
                }
                Commit(l, client);
            }
            catch(Exception er)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(er.Message);
            }

        }

        public static void Commit(List<Record> l, ElasticClient client)
        {
            BulkDescriptor a = new BulkDescriptor();
            foreach (var x in l)
                a.Index<Record>(op => op.Object(x).Index("index").Type("type"));
            var res = client.Bulk(d => a);
            Console.WriteLine("100 records more inserted.");
        }
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert 4 million records from Oracle to Elasticsearch table faster using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028381/how-to-insert-4-million-records-from-oracle-to-elasticsearch-table-faster-using)

Comment: No I have already implemented the techniques suggested in the solution to that question. I want further increase in speed.

Comment: Did you try to change bulk chunk size? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html#_how_big_is_too_big

Comment: @Rob I did try doing that, i varied the chunk size from 100 to 10,000.  I also have a large number of columns in the tables, is there any way I can make the fetching of 50 columns faster?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using lower level client i.e. ElasticSearchClient ?

Here is sample example -

```
//Fill data in ElasticDataRows

StringBuilder ElasticDataRows = new StringBuilder()
ElasticDataRows.AppendLine("{ \"index\":  { \"_index\": \"testindex\", \"_type\": \"Accounts\" }}");
ElasticDataRows.AppendLine(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(objXML, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true));

var node = new Uri(objExtSetting.SelectSingleNode("settings/ElasticSearchURL").InnerText);
var config = new ConnectionConfiguration(node);
ElasticsearchClient objElasticClient = new ElasticsearchClient(config);

//Insert data to ElasticSearch
var response = ExtractionContext.objElasticClient.Bulk(Message.ElasticDataRows.ToString());
```

ElasticSearchClient is not strongly typed like NEST. So you can convert your Class object data to JSON using NewtonSoft.JSON.

As per my testing this is more faster than NEST API.

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 0):

We have like 40-50 databases that we reindex each month. Each DB has from 1 to 8 mil rows. The difference is that i take the data from MongoDB. What i'm doing to make it faster is to use Parallel.Foreach with 32 threads running and inserting into elastic.I just insert one record because i need to calculate stuff for each of them but you just take them from the DB and insert them in elastic so the bulk insert seems better. You could try to use 3-4 threads and that bulk insert. 
So split your table into 4 then start different threads that bulk insert into elastic. From what i have seen i'm pretty sure that the part when you read from DB is taking the biggest part of the time. Also i think you should try to use a batch > 100.